# Custom module for form

Tags: forms

I have created form by implementing custom module. Can anybody please guide about writing submit function for my form.

```
function custom_form_module_form($form,&$form_state) {
  $form['name'] = array(
   '#title' => 'NAME',
   '#type' => 'textfield',
  );
  $form['company'] = array(
    '#title' => 'COMPANY',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
  );
  $form['phone'] = array(
    '#title' => 'PHONE',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
  );
  $form['email'] = array(
    '#title' => 'EMAIL',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
  );
  $form['message'] = array(
    '#title' => 'MESSAGE',
    '#type' => 'textarea',
  );
  $form['submit_button']=array(
    '#type'=>'submit',
    '#value'=>t('SEND'),
  );
  return $form;
}
```

**UPDATED**

```
 function custom_form_module_form_validate($form, &$form_state)
{
 if((!isset($_GET[($form_state['values']['name'])]))||
 (!isset($_GET[($form_state['values']['company'])]))||
 (!isset($_GET[($form_state['values']['phone'])]))||
 (!isset($_GET[($form_state['values']['email'])]))||
 (!isset($_GET[($form_state['values']['message'])])))
 {
  form_set_error(t('Please fill the entire form'));
 }
 $valid_email = $form_state['values']['email'];
 if (!valid_email_address($valid_email))
 {
  form_set_error('email', 'Sorry. Your email address,' . $valid_email . ', is not valid. Please submit a valid E-mail address.');
 }
 if(!($form_state['values']['company'] > 1))
 {
  form_set_error('company', t('Company does not appear to be valid.'));
 }
 if (!($form_state['values']['message'] > 2 ))
 {
  form_set_error('message', t('message does not appear to be valid.'));
 }
}
```

and below is my submit function. Is this right? because I am not receiving email as I specified my own email address.

```
function custom_form_module_form_mail($key, &$message, $params)
{
 $headers = array(
 'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
 'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8;',
 'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => '8Bit',
 'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal'
  );
  foreach ($headers as $key => $value)
  {
   $message['headers'][$key] = $value;
  }
  $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
  $message['body'] = $params['body'];
}

 function custom_form_module_form_submit($form, &$form_state) 
{
  $valid_email = $form_state['values']['email'];
  $body[] = 'Email: '.$valid_email.'<br />URL: '.request_uri();
  $to = 'me@example.com';
  $params = array(
  'body' => $body,
  'subject' => 'Welcome!',
  );
  if (drupal_mail('custom_form_module_form', 'some_mail_key', $to, language_default(), $params, TRUE))
  {
    drupal_set_message('Thanks, we will be in contact with more information soon.');     
  } 
  else
  {
    drupal_set_message('There was an error subscribing you. Please try again later');
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `custom_form_module_form_submit($form,&$form_state)`

Comment: @scott I have updated my answer, can you please point out my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `'#submit' => array('SOME_FUNCTION')` to your submit button and write your function normally.

Comment: Thanku @Matt, I have updated my answer. Still I am not receiving email.

Answer (score 2):

There's some hook functions you can use. my_module_my_form_validate($form, &$form_state) to validate the form, and my_module_my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) to submit.

[Example](https://www.drupal.org/node/717740)

Comment: Thanku @jance, I have updated my answer. Still I am not receiving email.

Answer (score 1):

I see there are couple of issues with your form validate function. First of we don' t need to write the $_GET to get the form_state values and  also  checking the string length of form values is not correct. I have corrected your validate function as.

```
 function custom_form_module_form_validate($form, &$form_state){
  if((!isset($form_state['values']['name']))||
 (!isset($form_state['values']['company']))||
 (!isset($form_state['values']['phone']))||
 (!isset($form_state['values']['email']))||
 (!isset($form_state['values']['message'])))
 {
   form_set_error(t('Please fill the entire form'));
  }
  $valid_email = $form_state['values']['email'];

  if (!valid_email_address($valid_email))
  {
    form_set_error('email', 'Sorry. Your email address,' . $valid_email . ', is not valid. Please submit a valid E-mail address.');
  }

  if(strlen($form_state['values']['company']) < 1)
  {
    form_set_error('company', t('Company does not appear to be valid.'));
  }
  if (strlen($form_state['values']['message']) < 2)
  {
    form_set_error('message', t('message does not appear to be valid.'));
  }
 }
```

Remember valid_email_address function should return true when the email is valid. The submit function is fine. If you have SMTP and SMTP port defined in your mail server then you will receive an email after submitting the function. If you are trying through the localhost you need to assign the SMTP server and SMTP port.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanku @Binod, yes I have to define SMTP port and server